# Jooq and postGIS

Tags: kotlin, postgis, jooq

I am trying to get Jooq working with GIS queries and found some samples on SO. I have a question regarding one of the samples. I found the following function which builds a Polygon ([How to select points within polygon in PostGIS using jOOQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370831/how-to-select-points-within-polygon-in-postgis-using-jooq)). Something like:

```
public static Field<?> stPolygon(Field<?> geom, int value) {
    return DSL.field("ST_Polygon({0}, {1})", Object.class, geom, DSL.val(value));
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can use this to build a polygon field from GIS coordinates (specified as doubles as a list of [latitude, longitude])

After that, if I want to select records where some column (point) lies within this polygon, how can I create my comparison operator. Would the `field.in` function work fine for such needs?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `IN` predicate to check if a geometry is *"in"* another geometry. You ahve to use the spatial predicates for that, instead. For example:

```sql
select st_contains(
  st_makepolygon(st_makeline(array[
    st_point(0, 0), 
    st_point(0, 1), 
    st_point(1, 1), 
    st_point(1, 0), 
    st_point(0, 0)
  ])),
  st_point(0.5, 0.5)
)
```

[Inspiration taken from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19046642/521799). If you have a table containing geometries for your points, you can also aggregate the points to an array like this:

```sql
select st_contains(
  st_makepolygon(st_makeline(array_agg(points.point))), 
  st_point(0.5, 0.5)
)
from points
```

#### Built in support starting from jOOQ 3.16

Starting from jOOQ 3.16, there's built-in GIS support in the commercial editions of jOOQ. Some natively supported functions can be seen in the manual:

- [Spatial functions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/spatial-functions/)
- [Spatial predicates](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/spatial-predicates/)